# Export and import dashboard in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I want to know if it is possible to export / import a dashboard configuration (widgets and their configuration) ?

The aim of that is to save a dashboard before modify it or test a dashboard on a test instance of Sonar and import it when finished on the "production" instance of Sonar.

Regards,

Stéphane

Comment: Any news to this 2016?
We are running SonarQube in Docker, and would like to store the dash board outside the container. Is the the dash board layout stored in the sonar database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's currently not possible.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the correct answer to the question. This is not possible. Full stop.

Comment: To further elaborate: Not easily; I hacked together a `.sql` file that would set up a custom dashboard by querying the database directly. So it's *technically* possible, but highly annoying and fragile. Hopefully SonarQube will get import/export abilities for profiles, dashboards, etc. someday.